# Myriad Pro iOS Rendering Issues

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm running into an issue rendering the following text example

```
UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200.0f, 200.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Bold" size:30.0f]];
[label setText:@"MÈssÅgËs"];
[label sizeToFit];
```

[image]

I then tried using the attributed string in iOS 6.0 >

```
UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200.0f, 200.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Bold" size:30.0f]];
[label setAttributedText: [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"MÈssÅgËs"]];
[label sizeToFit];
```

[image]

While the attributed string sized better, the text is clipped in both cases. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?